# intersection of Loci in Argand plane

Tags: complex-numbers

> In an Argand diagram, the loci
> $\arg(z-2i)=\frac{\pi}{6} $ and $ |z-3|=|z-3i|$ intersect at the point $P$.  Express the complex number represented by $P$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$

I tried to sketch the lock in argand(sorry for poor image)
[image]

Is the point $P$ intersect as in the image, and how to get the argument of $P$ as I'm getting the wrong answer of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ but the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of the complex number corresponding to $P$ is [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29#Definition) the angle of $OP$ counter-clockwise from the real axis.

But the line OP is parallel to (in fact, it is part of) the locus of $|z - 3| = |z - 3i|$.

Hence, the required argument is exactly the angle of the locus from the real axis. Now note that the locus is exactly the line $y = x$. This line lies $\frac{\pi}{4}$ above the real axis.

Comment: How do you calculate to get $\pi/4$    i try $\pi - 2\pi/3$ but the answer is $\pi/3$

Comment: By definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29#Definition) the argument of a complex number is the angle of $\vec{OP}$ from the real axis. "The angle of $P$" refers to this argument, not the angle of the vertex $P$.